# big.Int slice rewriting itself on append()

Tags: go, slice, bigint

I am trying to get a slice of `big.Ints` of the odd numbers between 3 and the square root of `i`.

When I run the following code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    i := big.NewInt(101)
    var divisorsOfPrime []*big.Int
    squareRoot := big.NewInt(0).Sqrt(i)
    for n := big.NewInt(3); n.Cmp(squareRoot) == -1; n.Add(n, big.NewInt(2)) {
        divisorsOfPrime = append(divisorsOfPrime, n)
    }
    fmt.Println(divisorsOfPrime)
}
```

I get the output:

```
[11 11 11 11]
```

But I expect the output:

```
[3 5 7 9 11]
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a slice of `*big.Int` in which you store the same pointer over and over again.

Instead, you need to store a copy of `n` on each iteration.

Replace:

```
divisorsOfPrime = append(divisorsOfPrime, n)
```

With:

```
nCopy := new(big.Int).Set(n)
divisorsOfPrime = append(divisorsOfPrime, nCopy)
```

By the way, this is not specific to `*big.Int`; as long as you're handling pointers you need to create new objects and store pointers to those new objects, not the original one. Notice that `n` is assigned exactly once.